# Plus not working in Scala interpreter

Tags: scala, interpreter

I am trying to sum a list using fold in the Scala interpreter, but it keeps giving me a strange error.  When I type this:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
(list :\ 0)(+)
```

I expect to get `6`.  However, the interpreter says

```
error: illegal start of simple expression
(list :\ 0)(+)
             ^
```

If I define my own function

```
def plus(a: Int, b: Int) = a+b
```

and call

```
(list :\ 0)(plus)
```

I do in fact get `6`.

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple here, but I can't figure it out, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The plus operator by itself is not a function it is a symbol and has no type. What you are looking for is the following

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
(list :\ 0)(_+_)
```

The _+_ is shorthand for an anonymous function that takes two parameters and calls the + method on the first parameter passing in the second.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(list :\ 0)(_ + _)
```

You need to use the wildcards to show the Scala compiler that you want to call the "+" method on first of the arguments instead of using the Tuple2 as an argument to a function itself.

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrect.  Rather the `plus` method defined above is a Function2 which has it's apply method called by the foldLeft.  Meanwhile the `+` operator is defined on the Int class as a method, so we need to tell the Scala compiler which object we want to call the `+` method on